# Bash: Check if a string contain specific alphabets and comma

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to parse and validate a string in Bash which is comma separated. The expected input is: X4,Y1,Z5

Conditions: The string should have only X,Y or Z alphabets, followed by any number. The string should not have any special characters other than comma. Please suggest.

X4,Y1,Z5 (This is OK)

Z2,y6,X1 (This is OK)

X3Y6,Z8 (This is not OK)

A1,B2,X8 (This is not OK)

N1P8* (This is not OK)

I have tried the following but this is not working as expected.

```
    if [[ ! $str =~ ['!@#$%^&*()_+'] ]] && [[ $str =~ [XYZxyz] ]]; then
            echo "OK"
    else
            echo "Not OK"
    fi
```

Comment: `[[ $str =~ ^[XxYyZz][0-9](,[XxYyZz][0-9])*$ ]]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But somehow this doesn't seem to work.

~~~
#!/bin/bash

check_input(){

        if [[ $1 =~ ^[XxYyZz][0-9](,[XxYyZz][0-9])*$ ]]; then
                echo "OK"
        else
                echo "Not OK"
        fi

}

clear
read userinput

check_input userinput
~~~

Comment: it if returns "Not OK", it is doing what you asked. `check_input uerinput` is testing if the literal string "userinput" matches. It won't. Perhaps you meant `check_input "$userinput"` ?

Comment: Thank you for that. A dumb mistake from my side. This is working.

Comment: Should each of X, Y, Z be used exactly once? Are the following strings valid: `X1,X1,X1`, `X1,Y2,Y3`, `X1,Y1`?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there are additional conditions of the problem that were implied but not emphasized, such as:

1. The numbers may have more then one digit.
2. Each of `X,Y,Z` letters should be used exactly once.

With that in mind, I think this code will do:

```bash
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[XxYyZz][0-9]+(,[XxYyZz][0-9]+){2}$ ]] && 
   [[ "$1" =~ .*[Xx].* ]] && 
   [[ "$1" =~ .*[Yy].* ]] && 
   [[ "$1" =~ .*[Zz].* ]] 
then
   echo OK
else
   echo Not OK
fi
```

Test cases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

check() {
    [[ "$1" =~ ^[XxYyZz][0-9]+(,[XxYyZz][0-9]+){2}$ ]] && 
    [[ "$1" =~ .*[Xx].* ]] && 
    [[ "$1" =~ .*[Yy].* ]] && 
    [[ "$1" =~ .*[Zz].* ]]
}

test_check() {
    # code - expected exit code
    # value - string to test
    while read code value; do
        check "$value"
        if [[ $? == $code ]]; then
            echo -e "\e[1;32mPassed:\e[0m $value"
        else
            echo -e "\e[1;31mFailed:\e[0m $value"
        fi
    done
}

test_check <<EOF
0 x1,y2,z3
0 X1,Y2,Z3
1 x,y,z
1 1,2,3
1 1x,2y,3z
0 z1,x2,y3
1 a1,b2,c3
1 x1
1 x1,y2 z1
1 x1,x2
1 x1;y2;z3
1 x1,y2
1 x1,y2,y3
0 x100,Y500,z0
0 x011,y015,z0
1 x1,x2,y3,z4
1 x1,y1,z1 .
EOF
```

---

*P.S.*
If any of the `X,Y,Z` may appear in the string more than once or not appear at all, then `[[ "$str" =~ ^[XxYyZz][0-9]+(,[XxYyZz][0-9]+)*$ ]]` should work. I added here `+` for digits to appear one or more times after the letter, and quoted `"$str"` in case if there's a space in it (or, to be precise, any character from `$IFS` variable).

Comment: Thanks you for this elaborate answer. For my requirement, the alphabets X,Y,Z can appear more than once, and the numbers can also be more than one digit.